# 502 Error after trading info between AWS Lambda functions

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm using two Lambda functions with different API Gateway resources to communicate with each other. Basically the architecture is like this :

api-gitlab-launcher ------requestId & pipelineId in headers---------->

<---response status 200 if correct information or else 404-----------database-manager

The code itself is this :

*First Lambda function : `api-gitlab-launcher`*

```
    api.post('/api-gitlab-launcher/create', async (lambdaRequest, lambdaResponse, next) => {
        config = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: "API_GATEWAY_URL/v1-test/database-manager/create-request",
            headers: {
                "request-id": requestNb,
                "pipeline-id": pipelineId
            }
        }
        console.log("find error") //appears in console log
        await axios(config)
            .then((lambdaResponse) => {
                    if (lambdaResponse.status == 200) {
                        console.log("1 request sent to database") // doesn't appear in console log
                    }
                }
            )
        lambdaResponse.json({requestId: requestNb})

    }
)
```

The second one is below :

*Second Lambda function : `database-manager`*

```
api.post('/database-manager/create-request', async (lambdaRequest, lambdaResponse, callback) => {
    await provideConnectionInfo()
    let connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: mySQLHost,
            user: mySQLUser,
            password: mySQLPassword,
            database: mySQLDatabase
        }
    )
    requestNb = lambdaRequest.headers['request-id']
    pipelineId = lambdaRequest.headers['pipeline-id']

    connection.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err
        let query = `INSERT INTO ec2_request VALUES (${requestNb},${pipelineId})`
        connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err
    let query = `INSERT INTO ec2_request VALUES (${requestNb},${pipelineId})`
    connection.query(query, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            let response = {
                "statusCode" : 404,
                "headers" : {} ,
                "body": JSON.stringify({message : "Record not inserted - Duplicate"}),
                "isBase64Encoded": false
            }
            return response
        } else {
            console.log("1 record inserted")
            let response = {
                "statusCode" : 200,
                "headers" : {} ,
                "body": JSON.stringify({message : "Record inserted"}),
                "isBase64Encoded": false
            }
            return response
        }

    })
   })
})
```

I also provide screenshots from the API Gateway :
[image: api-gitlab-launcher API]

[image: database-manager API]

My gut tells me it's related to the Lambda proxy configuration... But I'm not sure. Does someone see something else?

Comment: Did you check cloudwatch logs for any lambda errors?

Comment: @Marcin Yeah I did and no particular errors in the logs, just getting a 502 error on my Postman console

Answer (score 0):

Thats because, When you use `LambdaProxy` integration, the lambda should return the output in the following format. Please note that the body parameter should be a string. Otherwise 502 error is thrown.

```
{
  "isBase64Encoded": true|false,
  "statusCode": httpStatusCode,
  "headers": { "headerName": "headerValue", ... },
  "body": "..."
}
```

Reference: [Output format of a Lambda function for proxy integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format)

Comment: Tried doing that, I think I might be doing it wrong, the new code has been added to the post

Comment: What's the new results. Is the request reaching lambda. You can check cloud watch logs

Comment: the original request (api-gitlab-launcher --> database-manager) works and reaches its destination.
however the response from database-manager doesn't probably fit the output format, but I don't see why, 502 error from the first lambda function